# CommandButton don't work with Ajax and Param - JSF 2.0

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I was trying to implement a command button with `f:ajax` and `f:param` in my project, but I'm not being successfull.

I have one Bean called "disciplinaMBean" that have a @SessionScoped. In the respective JSF (let's say, index.xhtml) I have one `p:dataTable` showing some disciplines (this is what "disciplina" means in English :P). When I click in one row, a modal is opened showing to user options to "edit" or "delete" discipline. The selected object is stored in "disciplinaSelecionada" by `selection` attribute of [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) dataTable. **See by yourself:**

[image: "Nome" means Name. "Salvar" means Save and "Excluir" means delete]

The code of this modal is inside "edit.xhtml" file. **See the code below:**

```
<h:form>
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <h:inputText styleClass="form-control adicionar" id="nome"
            value="#{disciplinaMBean.disciplinaSelecionada.nome}">
    </h:inputText>

        <h:commandButton id="excluir" styleClass="btn btn-md btn-danger pull-left" value="Excluir" > 
        <f:param name="idDisciplina" value="#{disciplinaSelecionada.id}" />
            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{disciplinaMBean.deletar}" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

And the method "Deletar" (means delete) in disciplineMBean:

```
public void deletar(){
    String param1 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("idDisciplina");
    System.out.println("Disciplina deletada: " + param1);
    int idDisciplina = Integer.parseInt(param1);
    controleDisciplina.remover(idDisciplina);
}
```

I know I called the method because the log of console, but I can't delete the discipline because I have one error (a empty string is stored in "idDisciplina" param).

---

**Following is the error:**

```
Disciplina deletada: 
Nov 01, 2013 10:26:31 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: /edit.xhtml @31,72 listener="#{disciplinaMBean.deletar}": java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
javax.el.ELException: /edit.xhtml @31,72 listener="#{disciplinaMBean.deletar}": java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxHandler.java:447)
    at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:760)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:791)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1256)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at mbeans.DisciplinaMBean.deletar(DisciplinaMBean.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    ... 27 more
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have EL 2.2, you can do it like this (assuming `disciplinaSelecionada.id` is an `int`)

```
<h:commandButton id="excluir" action="#{disciplinaMBean.deletar(disciplinaSelecionada.id)}" styleClass="btn btn-md btn-danger pull-left" value="Excluir" />
```

....

```
public void deletar(int idDisciplina)
{
    System.out.println("Disciplina deletada: " + idDisciplina);
    controleDisciplina.remover(idDisciplina);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but, sorry...what's EL 2.2?

Comment: My teacher tell me JSF can't receive a parameter and must return a String, he isn't right?

Comment: @FernandoPaladini can i ask which OS you are using ? i like that

Comment: @Fernando: With EL 2.2 (expression language, these things: `#{...}`) you CAN pass parameters. And yes, you can return void if you want to stay on the current view. To perform a navigation rule, you can return a String. Which version/implementation of JSF are you using? If you're using JSF 2, then it's most likely that you're using EL 2.2.

Comment: @mohsin: it's Ubuntu.

Comment: @SimonArsenault Thanks for the informations Simon, my teacher lies to me!! Yes, I'm using JSF 2, so, I think I'm using EL 2.2. I will try what you said later, now I need a shower. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @SimonArsenault, I have one issue here :/ Can you help me solve this issue? About the error: http://notepad.cc/share/BmXSpGBx3w

Comment: @Fernando: I suggest you create a new question, or you edit your current question.

Comment: @FernandoPaladini thanks i saw OS review on youtube , but the problem is that i have dell laptop 5110 with 1 GM nvidia graphics card 4 RAM core i5 i had install linux ubuntu on it but laptop continuously heating up fans was moving fast, if i install Elementary OS then i will get that same problem ? and its free or paid OS like windows ?

Comment: Hi @mohsinazeem, Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu 12.04, so you may continue with the problem. Ubuntu and Elementary are both completly free, forever - and they're open-source too, what means much more security, more updates and features with user needs aim. Please, this's the best thing you can do, keep using a free and open-source OS - soon you'll know how better this is. About this bug, you can easily find people talking about that, try to solve your problem in similar questions, like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/206235/fan-very-loud-in-ubuntu-12-10 If you need, ask on askubuntu.com

Comment: @FernandoPaladini i have installed elementary OS its really fantastic (Y)